# What is the probability that 3 students spend an average of more than $7?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Each student spends money on snacks after school every afternoon:

Student 1's spending follows a normal distribution, he spends \$8 on average with a St. Dev of $3

Student 2's spending follows a normal distribution, he spends \$9 on average with a St. Dev of $2

Student 3's spending follows a normal distribution, he spends \$6 on average with a St. Dev of $5

What is the probability that on a given afternoon, the average of all 3 student's spending is more than $7?

I found that the chance of Student 1 spending more than $7 is .63056

Student 2's chance is .84134.

Student 3's chance is .42074

This is a total guess, but would it be the average of all 3?

(.63056+.84134+.42074)/3

Which would be 0.63088

Comment: Hello RaiderNAYSHUN, welcome to cross validated. I think you got the steps needed right, but the order has to be changed. Right now you are calculating the avarage chance of each one of them spending more than 7\$, but the question is for the avarage spendings of all 3 beeing over 7\$. So i think you have to calc the distribution of the average of spendings of the 3 students first and after that you calc the chance for spendings > 7. At least thats how i would understand it. Maybe it brings the same result as your approach? Not sure about that :)

Comment: You are implying student 3 will spend a *negative* amount 11.5% of the time.  Could you provide a reasonable interpretation of that?  You might also want to contemplate the (im)plausibility of the implicit assumption of *independent* spending amounts.

Comment: @TinglTanglBob Because "\$" is a $\TeX$ escape character on this site, you have to treat it specially.  Preceding each \$ with a backslash "\" does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the information about \\$. Your statement about negative spendings is great too. I wouldn't have thought about it at all if you didn't mention it.

Comment: Hi: you need to find the distribution of the average of 3 independent normal random variables with different variances. Then, once you have that, you don';t need to worry about the fact that there are three people. You can just view it as a problem about a random variable. The trick is that the mean of the new random variable is a linear combination of the 3 means where the coefficients are 1/3 1/3 and 1/3. So, you can find the distribution and associated parameters of the new random variable using that relation.

Comment: @whuber: Chance of finding a fiver while walking to the school cafeteria? (Good points of course. +1)

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem may be flawed. But it is important to know that the distribution of the sum of
independent normal random variables is normal. Here is a similar problem, but with very small probabilities of negative snack expenditures.
Suppose we have independent random variables:

$X_1 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1=9, \sigma_1=2),\,$ $X_2 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_2=10, \sigma_2=1),\,$ $X_3 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_3=12, \sigma_3=3).$

The probabilities of negative values for these three random variables are
computed in R (where `pnorm` denotes a normal CDF) as follows:

```
pnorm(0, 9, 2);  pnorm(0, 10, 1);  pnorm(0, 12, 3)
[1] 3.397673e-06
[1] 7.619853e-24
[1] 3.167124e-05
```

It is OK to model test scores, human heights, and other distributions as normal, but you have to be careful. Even though most of the probability in a normal distribution lies within $\mu \pm 3\sigma,$ the values do extend down to $-\infty$ and up to $\infty.$ So you have to be sure that probabilities of impossible negative events are negligible. (That is the point of @whuber's first
Comment.)

Then the distribution of the sum $S = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is
$$\mathsf{Norm}\left(\mu_S = \mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3,\; \sigma_S
= \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2}\right).$$

Then the average $A = S/3$ is distributed as 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_S/3, \sigma_S/3).$

I suppose you can find these formulas in your text or class notes, and then
find some probability such as $P(A < 10).$

---

*Note:* By simulating what happens on a very large number of afternoon snacks with these three students,
it is possible to approximate $P(A < 10).$

```
m = 10^6;  x1 = rnorm(m, 9, 2);  x2 = rnorm(m, 10, 1);  x3 = rnorm(m, 12, 3)  
X = cbind(x1, x2, x3);  a = rowMeans(X)
mean(a);  sd(a);  sqrt(14)/3;  mean(a < 10)
[1] 10.33198  #  aprx E(A) = 31/3 
[1] 1.246459  #  aprx SD(A)
[1] 1.247219  #  exact SD(A)
[1] 0.395034  #  aprx P(A < 10)
pnorm(10, 31/3, sqrt(14)/3)
[1] 0.394634  #  exact P(A < 10)
mean(c(pnorm(10,9,2), pnorm(10,10,1), pnorm(10,12,3)))
[1] 0.4813183 #  Your method of averaging probabilities doesn't work
```

The vector `a` contains a million average snack bills; `a < 10` is a logical vector with a million `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.
Its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s.